# When I run webpack --version, I see 1.14.0 even when I know I installed the latest

Tags: webpack

I am returning to a project using webpack and updating my npm modules.  When I update webpack to use the latest version using the command `npm install webpack@latest`, checking the version with the command `webpack --version` I see 1.14.0.  Is that correct?  I thought it should be like 4x or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install webpack` installs it in the local directory. Usually you don't have that in your `PATH` so you're most likely executing `webpack` that was installed globally with `npm install -g`.

Try upgrading the globally installed `webpack` with:

```
npm upgrade -g webpack
```

Alternatively you can use the locally installed `webpack` with:

```
`npm bin`/webpack --version
```

Or:

```
PATH=`npm bin`:$PATH webpack --version
```

Comment: OK, you are right! I thought I had removed it globally, but it was seemingly being referenced elsewhere in my operating system.  I think I might have installed nvm after I had installed webpack.  Thanks for that @kichik